# Confusion about "This statement cannot be proven"

Tags: logic

I'm wondering why this statement is taken to mean the below when it's true or false.

T: there is no proof (implying a true statement with no proof)

F: there is a proof (implying a false statement with a proof, or contradiction)

My question is, since the statement is referring to itself as a statement, why it doesn't mean the following.

T: there is no proof that "this statement cannot be proven," hence we can't prove that this true statement does not have a proof.

F: there is a proof that "this statement cannot be proven," hence there is a proof that this false statement cannot be proven, and there is no contradiction.

Comment: Not clear at all... what does it mean "T: there is no proof (implying a true statement with no proof)"? Do you mean that there is a statement, called T, asserting that there is no proof ... of what?" And similar for F.

Comment: And what about "This statement cannot be proven"? Do you mean it as a confused way to assert ""The statement S cannot be proven"?

Comment: See [Liar Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/) and [Self-Reference](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/) for some source to be studied.

Comment: T and F are when the statement is true and when it's false

Comment: Ok thanks. To say that "there is no proof (of statement S)" simply means that, in the context of a relevant mathematical theory, statement S cannot be proved. A typical example is the axiom of parallel in the context of Euclidean geometry: the said axiom cannot be proved from the remaining axioms of Euclidean geometry; see [Non-Euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry)

Comment: Other examples [Continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) for Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory and [Paris–Harrington theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem) for Peano arithmetic.

Comment: To give context, the statement is often used to show an example of a contradiction when it's false, therefore claiming that there are true statements that can't be proven. My question is since it's a statement referring to itself, why isn't the meaning more like the second F in my post, hence avoiding any contradiction.

Comment: If you are alluding to the wll-(un)known [Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/), the issue is a little bit thorny... Technical details are needed in order to meaningfully discuss it.

Comment: Yes, it is so-called [Liar Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/): a statement called **L** written as "**L** is false" produces a "paradoxical" result: If we assume that the sentence ‘**L** is false’ is true, then we are forced - by what **L** asserts -  that **L** is false. But **L** is exactly the sentence ‘**L** is false’, so we  conclude that if **L** is true, then **L** is false. Conversely assuming that **L** is false...  But if every sentence is true or false, given the above argument, we have that **L** is both true and false. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Since L is "L is false" shouldn't saying "L is false" mean that "'L is false' is false," hence L is true?

Comment: Yes, you have completed the "dots" above: Conversely assuming that L is false... we conclude that L is true. Thus L is both true and false.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ah, yes. Haha. What I was imagining though, is that "this statement cannot be proven" is also a meta-level statement about the statement itself, and doesn't suffer the contraction that comes with a statement pondering the truth of itself.

Comment: Trust in the formal system is what is giving these sentences their truth, if you trust the formal system you must equally trust these sentences. Some degree of self reference isn’t a problem. I’m not sure what you’re tying to alleviate.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that *S* and *B* are various (sets of) sentences such that we say (note: we are loosely mixing the normal way of FOL with [quantification over propositions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/#ProQua)):

1. ∃*B*∀*S*¬(*S* ⊢ *B*)
2. ¬∃*S*(*S* ⊢ *B*)

This is different from:

3. ∀*S*¬(*S* ⊢ (¬∃*S*(*S* ⊢ *B*)))

Proof is usually taken as factive, meaning that if *T* is proven, then *T* is true. If *B* were proven, *B* would be true, but since *B* says that *B* isn't proven, then a proof of *B* would be a proof that there is no proof of *B*. (C.f. the question of, ["This very sentence is unknown."](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemic-paradoxes/#KnoPar))

What might still be perplexing is how proving that something is unprovable is not itself a sort of proof of the original thing. The solution, such as it is, is that in the systems where such statements are evaluated, there are delicate separations of levels/orders so that, "It is (un)proven that it is (un)proven that..." is on a different level than just, "It is (un)proven that..." so that a second-level proof of a first-level unproof doesn't transform into a first-level proof.

Answer (score -1):

This statement (referring to itself, G) is unprovable from the axioms of system S = G (Gödel sentence).

G is true: Ok.
G is false: *There's proof* that *there's no proof* of G. Contradiction.

There's a G in any system S or system S is *incomplete* (contains true and yet unprovable statements ).

That's how - *cogito* - the story goes.

---

Do *nfr* things.

Comment: If G states its own unprovability in S, then either G is true and unprovable in S, or G is false and provable in S. There is no contradiction. In the first case S is incomplete, in the second case S is unsound.

Comment: Indeed, a matter most painful for the mind.